# Iced (cold) coffee stronger than hot?

Tags: iced-coffee

Generally, it is a fact that hot drinks make us calm. That is the suggestion from doctors - to drink a hot drink before going to bed. So, is iced coffee stronger because that triggers our metabolism?

From the sources so far (searching on cold VS hot coffee) I have found this:

> Grab a cold-brewed coffee before going to the gym. Yes – coffee made
>   from cold water. Surprisingly, cold brew coffee contains many
>   antioxidants and healthy body boosters for better workouts. Skip the
>   shakes and vitamin waters – simply power-up with a cold brew and head
>   for the gym.

The link is given here:
http://www.madescolabs.com/accelerate-your-weight-loss-goals-with-cold-brew-coffee/

I am guessing the cold coffee is stronger because of the temperature (metabolism trigger) and not because of a chemical reaction with the substances.

PS: Some examples of cold (iced) coffee can be:

a) The greek frappe which is instant coffee (nescafe mainly), shaken with water and with extra ice cubes added.

b) Freddo Espresso (cold Espresso) which is a double Espresso coffee. It is then blended for 8-10 seconds with 3 big ice cubes. That releases some flavours and the final result is poured into a glass with 1-2 ice cubes.

Comment: You need to be careful: “Cold brew” is a way to prepare coffee, cold coffee is - simply - cold coffee, probably hot-brewed and cooled afterwards. Just to avoid a mixup.

Answer (score 3):

**Stronger: No.** Subltle differences: Yes.

For people who tolerate caffeine, want the longevity benefits, and looking for something gentler on your stomach with **slightly** less caffeine, cold brew is your cup of joe.

Hot brewed coffee has more anti-oxidants and a lower pH.  Cold-brewed has less acid and thus for many palates is 'milder'.  The caffeine content of the 2 is basically the same.

In summary:

'Hot brewed coffee could be better for you than cold, since heating it could increase the availability of antioxidants in your cup — but more **research** is needed to determine if the benefits are significant enough to warrant making the switch.' The individual's palate so for should be the final arbiter.

https://coach.nine.com.au/2017/09/20/09/51/cold-brew-coffee-health-benefits
https://www.mindbodygreen.com/articles/is-cold-brew-coffee-better-for-you-than-regular-coffee